# Jmeter request erroring with following response "Failed to identify Event named"

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter when I reproduce the test I recorded I get a 500 response code with the following Runtime Exception

> org.apache.cocoon.ProcessingException: Failed to execute pipeline.:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to identify Event named MIDA9C32817-C380-4BF8-9D1A-358BF0BB5059

I thought the event name had to be dynamically extracted from the responses when I first login, in the same way as the session uid. I am not sure why this isn't working.

Please find some screenshot to illustrate the above.

The picture below is the general view of the test plan. The response data tab that is shown corresponds to the request that is failing. You can find the exception highlighted in yellow.
[image: The test with the response]

The following picture is the continuation of the above and displays the request tab information of the request that is failing.
[image: The request data Tab]

One more tab of the request that is failing. Up to this picture three tabs are shown as part of the same request.

[image: The request Sample request Tab]

This picture shows that I substitute the value of the ESR_PROCESS_EVENT parameter from something like this 0cc9d524-9ca8-4bce-92dd-98ac2c965e23 to ${ESR_PROCESS_EVENT}
[image: HTTP request that is failing]

The value held in ${ESR_PROCESS_EVENT} is extracted from the regular expression shown below. Which appears in the cookie data that is held when I first login the application (extracted from the response which is located in the left hand side menu and highlighted in yellow shown in the last picture)
[image: The extractor]

[image]

Anyone can clarify why I get the event name exception please?

Comment: I have edited the post by adding a little description before each picture. Hope that helps to understand the issue a bit better

Comment: It seems that the number I am extracting and using it as a value has nothing to with what the event name should be. Because the hash value I was trying to use in the event name is generated once and used throughout the session. When it actually each event uses a different hash value and therefore the request erroring. I am still figuring out what the value should be.